# Liquid filter for two different tags

Tags: liquid

I need to create a liquid tag/filter which only displays the required data from the placeholder, if the condition for another placeholder is fulfilled.

Actual: 
I have a web-form with different questions and different answers.

A question has the placeholder: {{attendees[0].custom_questions[0].name}}

An answer has the placeholder: {{attendees[0].custom_questions[0].answer}}

-> there will only be one attendee, so attendees[0] will not change.

-> the order of the custom_questions.name and custom_questions.answer can change.

-> There are 15 different questions and answers

Expected: If custom_questions.name == "Test Question" the custom_questions.answer "Test Answer" to that question should be displayed.

To clarify:

If "Test Question" is f.e. {{attendees[0].custom_questions[8].name}}, the right answer will be {{attendees[0].custom_questions[8].answer}}

**BUT**
"Test Question" can sometimes also be {{attendees[0].custom_questions[9].name}} or another number in the array.

**The answer should only be displayed if the question == "Test question"**

Can someone help?

**UPDATE**

I´m using a basic html editor to create pdf-files. this editor uses liquid tags as placeholders from a data base. the database is filled by a web form. 
the placeholders (from the database) can't be edited.

Code example:

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; height: 13px;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 13px;">
<td style="width: 100%; height: 13px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18pt; position: relative; left: -0.5cm;">VOUCHER FOR {% for p in attendees %} {% if p.ticket.id == "103391" or p.ticket.id == "103411" or p.ticket.id == "103392" %} PRESS BADGE {% else %} VIP PRESS INVITATION {% endif %} {% endfor %}</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In this code you can see the usage of liquid code.

For this task I need to work with two different placeholders:

{{attendees[0].custom_questions[0].name}}

{{attendees[0].custom_questions[0].answer}}

These are arrays where there will only be one attendee but there are up to 15 questions.

Unfortunately, the order is not stable. Sometimes the needed answer is number 4 and sometimes it is number 9.

I need the answer to the question called "Test Question".
The answer placeholder will always have the same array number as the question name.

My idea:

```
{% if attendees[0].custom_questions[0].name == "Test Question" %}{{attendees[0].custom_questions[0].answer}}{% elsif attendees[0].custom_questions[1].name == "Test Question"%}{{attendees[0].custom_questions[1].answer}}{% elsif attendees[0].custom_questions[2].name == "Test Question"%}{{attendees[0].custom_questions[2].answer}}..........
```

Does not work.

Can you help?

Comment: Would you please add your code to your question so what you want to achieve would be clearer ;).?

Comment: new update to the question

Comment: Please would you also make your code readable by indenting and creating new line each time you open something. So, your question is really unclear. TIA.